# fabric check if symlink exist and delete if exist

Tags: python, django, fabric

I am using fabric for site deployment. When i deploy I want to check if my project is exist in site enable. If exist i want to delete it. I guess my site inside site_enabled is symlink. I am doing something like:

```
vhost_check = '/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/%(project_name)s' % env
print vhost_check

if exists('-f {}'.format(vhost_check)):
    print "exists"
    sudo('rm -f {}'.format(vhost_check))
```

but it still giving me error. I am checking if site exists, if not I am creating my project in site_enable. It gives me error saying my site already exist.

How can I check if it exists and if it exists I want to delete it.
Thank you

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`fabric.contrib.files.is_link(path, use_sudo=False, verbose=False)`](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.12/api/contrib/files.html#fabric.contrib.files.is_link)
It is already built into fabric. No need to write a new method to do this.

For exmaple

```
from fabric.contrib.files import is_link
if is_link(vhost_check):
   sudo('rm %s' $vhost_check)
else:
   pass
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you're still searching for a solution, because some time passed by, but in case, here is a solution:

```
from fabric.api import sudo

vhost_check = '/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/%(project_name)s' % env


def check_symlink():
    """Check symlink and remove, if exist."""
    exists = sudo('test -f {vhost_check}'.format(vhost_check=vhost_check))

    if exists:
        print 'exists'
        sudo('rm {vhost_check}'.format(vhost_check=vhost_check))

    else:
       pass
```